# OWL Carousel 2 with AngularJS 2 - How To

Tags: angular, owl-carousel

Does anyone know how to use **owl carousel 2.0 with angular 2**?
What needs to be done when trying to load the carousel items from an  observable (async!). How to re-initialize the carousel? Currently the items appear way too large.

There seems to be a solution for angular 1.x in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27988502/applying-angularjs-ng-repeat-to-owl-carousel) but as a angular 2 newbie i failed to find out how to migrate the solution to angular 2.0.

Any help is highly appreciated!